# Running Selenium Grid node & hub with Bamboo Integration

Tags: robotframework, bamboo, selenium-grid

I was able to run web UI tests using Robot Framework with Selenium Grid on my local machine.

```
HUB: $ java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0.jar -role hub -port 4444
PORT: $ java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0.jar -role node -hub http://localhost:4444
TEST: java -options myUiTest.robot
```

However, when I run the same test via bamboo (robotframework:run) using the same hub & port instance, the test fails with the error "BadStatusLine: ''".

How do I make Bamboo see the port and the hub?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I apparently I did not specify the correct IP Address of the server in my test case. That's why it couldn't connect to the remote webdriver.
I had to replace:

```
${executor}=    Evaluate    str('http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub')
```

with:

```
${executor}=    Evaluate    str('http://myIPAddress:4444/wd/hub')
```

And use it to connect to the remote webdriver:

```
Create Webdriver    Remote    myAlias    desired_capabilities=${capabilities}    command_executor=${executor}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running the hub all the time?

Selenium grid just passes a session to bamboo so you can run multiple nodes without having to bring them down.  Our grid currently has 5 web browsers, 3 android emulators, 3 iOS simulators, all of which just get passed between multiple builds in our system.

If you are only running a single node, there isn't a real reason to build a hub.

Comment: Hello, thanks. As you've mentioned, no need to build a hub. I tried running only a remote webriver (java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.0.1.jar). It works in my local machine too. But it still doesn't work with bamboo (BadStatusLine). Any ideas?